# How to fit exactly openlayers map into a custom div tag?

Tags: php, html, css, openlayers

I am new to web mapping and trying some code to include an openlayers map into a div including openlayers code from php. It will show divs but the map goes down the map. What shall be done to correct my code? The php is included in map div

```
        <?php  include_once("gps_track.php") ;  ?>


        #map{
            clear:both;
            float:left;
            border:3px solid #330066;
            height:500px;
            width:70%;

        }
```

and have attribute section on the right with css

```
               #attribute{
              float:right;
              border:3px solid #334353;
              height:500px;
              width:28%;
                  }
```

Should I use extra divs from openlayes for css?

the js code is:

```
    var lat=27.6167
    var lon=85.5500
    var zoom=13

    var map;

    function init() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map ("map", {
            controls:[
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()],
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34),
            maxResolution: 156543.0399,
            numZoomLevels: 19,
            units: 'm',
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
            displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        } );

        layerMapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik("Mapnik");
        map.addLayer(layerMapnik);
        layerCycleMap = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.CycleMap("CycleMap");
        map.addLayer(layerCycleMap);
        layerMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
        map.addLayer(layerMarkers);

    var google_map_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        'Google Map Layer',
        {}
    );

    var google_hybrid_layer=new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        'Google Hybrid',
        {type:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID}
    );

    map.addLayer(google_map_layer);
    map.addLayer(google_hybrid_layer);


        // Add the Layer with the GPX Track
        var lgpx = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Kathmandu University", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "ku.gpx",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GPX()
            }),
            style: {strokeColor: "green", strokeWidth: 5, strokeOpacity: 0.5},
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        });

        //Adding vector layer for editing

    var vector_layer=new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
        'Editable Vectors'
    );
    //add a vector editing control
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(vector_layer));


        map.addLayer(vector_layer);
        map.addLayer(lgpx);

        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
        map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);

        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21, 25);
        var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
        var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/img/marker.png',size,offset);
        layerMarkers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat,icon));
    }
    popup= new OpenLayers.Popup("This is gps track",
                                    new OpenLayers.LonLat(85.5500,27.6167),
                                    new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
                                    "Dhulikhel",
                                    true);
    map.addPopup(popup);
    alert("sorry no alert");
</script>
```

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear to me and you're not showing the javascript code which initialises OpenLayers. If you initialise OpenLayers with `var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');`, the div with id `map` will be filled with the map. Thus, you should just use CSS to set the correct size of your div that holds the map and the map will have that very same size. If this is not an answer to your question, maybe you could add a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) to clarify your question.

Comment: I worked with css but it didn't worked. I have now attached openlayers code as well saved in .php.

Comment: When I loaded a function init() on my index page it just worked fine and adjusted in my map div. But what will be the cause of errors in these sort of problems so that I will be aware in future.

Comment: I can't see where you're calling the init() function. If you want to make it clear, put your code in `jsfiddle.net` and post the url of your fiddle in a new comment on this question.